# Can I reinstall Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials?

Tags: reinstall

I need to reinstall this on a new server setup.  I need to do-over since it made my domain a .local.  I need .com.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2830511

I have installed only 1 time, and it's activated.  it will be reinstalled on the SAME server.  Will I have a activation problem doing so?

thanks!

Comment: Would configuring an alternate UPN suffix not fix your problem? Why do you need a .com domain?

Comment: You shouldn't have any problem.

Comment: Because I hear that the .local isn't good practice or the best option?  I've read too many arguments about it and want my server to start off on the right foot with a domain such as SERVER.MYDOMAIN.com (I own my .com domain name).  I also want it to be easy for users if remoting in etc.  I guess I need for better consistency.  rather refer as MYDOMAIN.com versus MYDOMAIN.local.  I don't understand why so many are against or for .local?  But what I don't really understand (besides simplicity) is why MS makes it this way with Essentials?  Any advice?  thanks!

Comment: Definitely don't name it the same as your public domain name. Use an unused subdomain of your public domain, like `AD.MYDOMAIN.COM`. That is the current best practice.

Comment: yeah, that is what I also found out.  so the goal is SERVER.MYDOMAIN.com, not just MYDOMAIN.com like my public domain.  Thank you Joe! ; )

Comment: Technically your server would be `SERVER.AD.MYDOMAIN.COM`.

Comment: Ok, now I am good and confused.  Please see this topic: http://serverfault.com/questions/702920/windows-server-2012-r2-essentials-unable-to-install-using-com-etc-domain-suff

Comment: Goal achieved! DOMAIN:  AD.MYDOMAIN.COM